# I am making a website for a school project and I am having problems with different resolutions positioning elements of the site

Tags: html, css, web, resolution

As mentioned in the title I am making a website for school, and part way through creating it I discovered that when I displayed the page on a screen with a different resolution that the elements on my site do not line up correctly. I am fairly new to html/css and am stuck at how to fix this. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the body section of my html file:

```
        <a href='index.html'>
        <img src="Images\Logo\Logopng.png" alt="Explore Germany"/> 
        </a> <!-- Inserting Logo at top of page -->
            <div id="whitespace">
            <a> <img  id="twitt" src="Images\images\twitter_web.png"> </a>
            <a> <img  id="email" src="Images\images\email_web.png"> </a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <div id="top" class = "line black"></div>  <!-- This is the black line just above the links at top of page -->
                <ul>            <!-- A list with links to external pages for my header -->
                <li><a id="menu" href="why.html">Why Germany?</a></li>   
                <li><a id="menu" href="where.html">Where In Germany?</a></li>
                <li><a id="menu" href="language.html">German Language</a></li> 
                <li><div  class="box grey"></div></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="bottom" class = "line black"></div>     <!-- This is the black line just below the links at top of page -->
            </nav>

    </header>

    <img id="map" src="Images\images\Map.png">

    <img class="Icon" id="Hamburg" src="Images\images\Icon.png">  <div id="Hamburg_Name">Hamburg</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Berlin" src="Images\images\Icon.png">    <div id="Berlin_Name">Berlin</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Dresden" src="Images\images\Icon.png">    <div id="Dresden_Name">Dresden</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Dusseldorf" src="Images\images\Icon.png"> <div id="Dusseldorf_Name">Dusseldorf</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Cologne" src="Images\images\Icon.png">    <div id="Cologne_Name">Cologne</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Frankfurt" src="Images\images\Icon.png">  <div id="Frankfurt_Name">Frankfurt</div>
    <img class="Icon" id="Munich" src="Images\images\Icon.png">     <div id="Munich_Name">Munich</div>


    <div id="info">
        <div id="name">Click on an Icon on the<br> map to learn more about that city</div>
        <div id="info1"></div>
        <img src="" id="cityImg">
        <div id="head"></div>
        <div id="info2"></div>
    </div>



            <div id="foot" class="footer black"> <!-- This is for the black box at the bottom which is the footer -->
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="wfooter" href="index.html">Home</a></li>          <!-- This is a list of the links and lines in the footer -->
                        <li><a id="wfooter" href="why.html">Why Germany</a></li>
                        <li><a id="wfooter" href="where.html">Where In Germany</a></li>
                        <li><a id="wfooter" href="language.html">German Language</a></li>
                        <li><a id="wfooter2"><i>@Copyright Jack Ryan 2017 Contact: jryan@student.christscollege.com<i></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>






</body>
```

And this is my css file:

```
body {
    width: 800px;
    height:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;

}

p {
    font-size: 15%
    font:;  
}

header img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 350px;
    margin-top:15px;
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width:100px;
}

#gate {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:16px;

}


html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
}   

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:-40px;
    padding: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}



#menu {
    margin-left:93px;
    max-width: 800px;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    padding:12px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    color:black;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#menu:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.box {
    width:800px;
    height: 40px;
}
.grey {
    background:#dddddd;
}

.line {
    width:800px;
    height:2px;
}

.black {
    background:#000000;
}

#top {
    position:relative;
    bottom:-18px;
}

#bottom {
    position:relative;
    bottom:16px;
}

.back {
    width:800px;
    height:1225px;

}

.backwhere {
    width:800px;
    height:935px;

}

.darkgrey {
    background:#fefdfd;
}

.side  {
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}

.footer {
    width:775px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:12.5px;
    border-radius:12.5px;
}

#body {
    width:775px;
    margin-left:12.5px;

}

#footer {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
    top:10px;
    color:white;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#footer2 {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:20px;

}

#footer:hover {
    color:lightgray;
}

#twitt {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:750px;
    top:-125px;
}

#email {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:695px;
    top:-186px;
}

#whitespace {
    height:0px;
}

#map {
    position:absolute;
    left: 270px;
    margin-left:0px;
    max-height:85%;
    max-width:85%;
}

#hamburg {
    position:absolute;
    top:280px;
    left:480px;
}

#hamburg_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:280px;
    left:500px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}


#Berlin {
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
    left:620px;
}

#Berlin_Name {
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
    left:640px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}


#Dresden {
    position:absolute;
    top:425px;
    left:640px;
}

#Dresden_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:425px;
    left:660px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";

}


#Dusseldorf {
    position:absolute;
    top:435px;
    left:360px;
}

#Dusseldorf_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:435px;
    left:380px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}

#Cologne {
    position:absolute;
    top:460px;
    left:380px;
}

#Cologne_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:460px;
    left:400px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}


#Frankfurt {
    position:absolute;
    top:510px; 
    left:455px;
}


#Frankfurt_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:510px; 
    left:475px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}


#Munich {
    position:absolute;
    top:620px;
    left:550px;
}


#Munich_name {
    position:absolute;
    top:620px;
    left:570px;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
}

.Icon{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#info{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 730px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 550px;
    width: 325px;
    border-radius:12.5px;
}

#Name {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    font-size:25px;
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:10px;
}

#info1 {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    font-size:15px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:40px;

}

#info2 {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    font-size:15px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:320px;

}

#cityImg {
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:15px;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:200px;

}
#head {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    font-size:25px;
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:290px;

}

#foot {
position:absolute;
top:760px;
}

#wfooter {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
    top:-5px;
    color:white;
    margin-left:5px;
}

#wfooter2 {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top:-10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    font-weight:lighter;
    top:175px;
    left:300px;
    z-index:1;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    font-style:normal;
    color:black;
    font-weight:lighter;
    font-size:16px;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:300px;
    max-width:700px;
    z-index:1; 

}


#Central_Why  {
    border-radius:15px;
    border:3px solid black;
    max-width:775px;
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:285px;
    z-index:0;
    border-color:black;
}

#Why_Body {
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    left:285px;
    top:630px;
    font-weight:lighter;

}


#Oktoberfest {
    position:absolute;
    font-family:"Proxima Nova";
    left:285px;
    top:690px;
    font-weight:lighter;

}
```

Comment: you have to make your website responsive..
have a look at this
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: Ok so to help the community to help you for something, you need to provide some more details. Try to read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solutions. a simple one would be @media queries. these ask the browser what size it is and then give it different instructions depending on size

for example adding

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
    width: 600px;
    height:1000px;
   }
}
```

now your screen will load a different height and width depending on screen size. you can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

and here is a set of sizes to work to: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

there will always be differences on uses screens so you have to build anticipating that, so test it on lots by resizing your browser or if oyu get more into webdesign using a site like this: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

also, i'm sorry about all the downvotes. the community here aren't really newbie friendly. its an amazing resource, but more where experienced (/semi experienced) developers come to support each other.. i guess that culture has developed so it doesn't become like a school for teaching basics.

speaking as someone who closed more than one account because my questions we not well received, i'd suggest googling for a forum or slack group specifically for people starting out to get advice and help, there are plenty of devs out there eager to help those just starting out